# How to get Date (yyyy/mm/dd) from ticks without using an instance/helper of/from Datetime C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extract date from ticks.

Am I right that, a millisecond is 10000 ticks. 
and a day is 864000000000 ticks and a month 
is 26784000000000 and a year is 316224000000000.

but when I use these in computations, I get wrong date :(.

It could have been easy using Datetime parse but, for some reasons they say that I shouldn't rely on it as it is rather slower.

Would appreciate your help. Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
//assume this for now 
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
char[] ashigakaricom= new char[] { 'yyyy','-','mm','-','dd','-','H','H',':','M','M',':','S','S',':','m','m','m' }; 
long ticks = time.Ticks;
 int n1 = (int)(ticks >> 32);
 int n2 = (int)ticks;
 if (n2 < 0) 
n1++; 

ticks = (((Math.BigMul(429497, n2) - (int)(Math.BigMul(1161359156, n2) >> 32) - Math.BigMul(1161359156, n1)) >> 32)) + Math.BigMul(n1, 429497); n1 = (int)(ticks >> 32); 
n2 = (int)ticks; 


if (n2 < 0) 
n1++; 

int q = n1 * 50 + ((50 * (n2 >> 16)) >> 16) - (int)(System.Math.BigMul(1244382467, n1) >> 32) - 1; 

int r = (int)(ticks - System.Math.BigMul(q, 86400000)); 

if (r > 86400000) 
r -= 86400000; 



//so on
```

Comment: Which data type do you use for the calculation?
For example, using an Integer data type may result in incorrect calculations (since Integers will always be whole)

Comment: i need to output the date in char, delimited by -.

Comment: please show your code... what is not working ? several points: this approach is highly problematic and should NOT be used... optimize only things that are really a bottleneck and I really doubt that in any application `DateTime` is the bottleneck!

Comment: It's not clear what you've got to do - or who "they" are. You have a number of ticks - but since which epoch? It's not clear what your input is, or what your expected output is. How would `DateTime.Parse` help when it's the *output* which is meant to be a string?

Comment: How wrong your date is? Date, Month is correct and year is not?

Comment: What is your objection to using the ticks to create a DateTime? Via the DateTime(long) constructor. Since this is a struct there is no GC impact etc here

Comment: can't paste it here, so I'll add it on the answer part...

Comment: DateTime time = DateTime.Now;//assume this for now
        char[] ashigakaricom= new char[]
            {
            'yyyy','-','mm','-','dd','-','H','H',':','M','M',':','S','S',':','m','m','m'    
            };
        long ticks = time.Ticks;
        int n1 = (int)(ticks >> 32);

        int n2 = (int)ticks;

        if (n2 < 0)

            n1++;

        ticks = (((Math.BigMul(429497, n2) - (int)(Math.BigMul(1161359156, n2) >> 32) - Math.BigMul(1161359156, n1)) >> 32))

        + Math.BigMul(n1, 429497);
        n1 = (int)(ticks >> 32);
        n2 = (int)ticks;

Comment: if (n2 < 0)

            n1++;

        int q = n1 * 50 + ((50 * (n2 >> 16)) >> 16) - (int)(System.Math.BigMul(1244382467, n1) >> 32) - 1;
        int r = (int)(ticks - System.Math.BigMul(q, 86400000));
        if (r > 86400000)
            r -= 86400000;

Comment: int unit = (int)(Math.BigMul(r >> 7, 9773437) >> 32) >> 6;
        n2 = (unit * 13) >> 7;
        n1 = r - 3600000 * unit;
       


        ashigakaricom[12] = ((char)(n2 + '0'));
        ashigakaricom[13] = ((char)(unit - 10 * n2 + '0'));
        unit = (int)((Math.BigMul(n1 >> 5, 2290650)) >> 32);
        n1 -= 60000 * unit;
        n2 = (unit * 13) >> 7;
        ashigakaricom[14] = ((char)(n2 + '0'));
        ashigakaricom[15] = ((char)(unit - 10 * n2 + '0'));
        unit = ((n1 >> 3) * 67109) >> 23;
        n1 -= 1000 * unit;
        n2 = (unit * 13) >> 7;

Comment: ashigakaricom[16] = ((char)(n2 + '0'));
        ashigakaricom[17] = ((char)(unit - 10 * n2 + '0'));
        n2 = (n1 * 41) >> 12;
        ashigakaricom[19] = ((char)(n2 + '0'));
        n1 -= 100 * n2;
        n2 = (n1 * 205) >> 11;

 //so on

Comment: see that it involves bit-shifting and multiplication.

Comment: Could you please add this code to the post, it will be easier to read it with syntax highlighted. Thanks!

Comment: @SeyrenAznable how do you account for things liks DST and leap years ? Again - this is NOT the right approach IMHO!

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov 

I tried doing that earlier, but I can't.. I just recently joined, few minutes ago. :( will try again and see.

Comment: And again I ask; what is wrong with new DateTime(ticks) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several ideas on this:

- If you're missing correct year -- probably incorrect starting point for this ticks calculation was assumed. For C# it's not beginning of Unix epoch (1st January 1970), but "beginning of days" (1st January 0001);
- Incorrect date, hour or minute -- this may something to do with leap year.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard Jan 1 0001 as "beginning of days" - merely, just another epoch that gives a bit more range before the '70s

Comment: It in a quotes. Should I call it "not Unix epoch" instead?

Comment: thanks! seems like I need to consider the epoch. 

hours, minute,sec and millis are all working fine. 

I'll consider this as an answer. I too believed Datetime.Parse is OK, but there's effort already in the code, and I guess I'll just add some lines to include year, month and day.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> and a month is 26784000000

Ah - sorry, what planet do you live oh? On mine (called "Earth") months have between 28 and 31 days, so they can not be standardized to a specific number of ticks.

The best you can come up with is IIRC

There is NO Way around a working calendar for what you try to achieve, which means a lot of mainteannce and overhead..5 hours average per month. Just use what .NET provides - this is a lot of work to duplicate with zero gain.

Comment: You have months with 38 days ? I could use one of those ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(10000);
 or: TimeSpan elapsedSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(10000);
 then use: elapsedSpan.Milliseconds, elapsedSpan.Days
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx

P/S: 316224000000000 ticks equal 366 days.

Answer (score 0):

A millisecond may be any number of ticks (depending on what you use). regardless, even if you have the number of days since epoch (lets assume 1-1-1970), you will still have a hard time calculating the amount of days in each month (e.g. February).